# How to fill default text into QInputDialog

Tags: qt

I am trying to fill the default text  into LineEdit field of QInputDialog (like filling the old value to rename, for example). Here is the code:

```
  bool dialogResult;
  QInputDialog *renameDialog = new QInputDialog();
  renameDialog->setTextValue("Test"); // has no effect
  QString result = renameDialog->getText(0, "Rename Label", "New name:", QLineEdit::Normal,
                                         "", &dialogResult);
  if(result.length() > 0 && dialogResult) setText(result);
```

How can I set a value to `InputDialog` to make it filled by default?

Comment: You're setting the default text value to "" when you call the getText function.

Comment: Thanks. How can I make it work then?

Comment: Replace "" with your default text. For example: `QString result = renameDialog->getText(0, "Rename Label", "New name:", QLineEdit::Normal, "Test", &dialogResult);`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to pass the default text as fifth parameter:

```
QString result = renameDialog->getText(0, "Rename Label", "New name:", QLineEdit::Normal,
                                       "DEFAULT TEXT", &dialogResult);
```

See also [QInputDialog::getText()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtwidgets/qinputdialog.html#getText):

> ... text is the default text which is placed in the line edit ...